# Force WWW to use HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

How do I force www to use https and not just http?

For example, when visiting http://www.example.com it redirects to https://www.example.com but if you don't include the www, you don't get redirected to the SSL version.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/crossdomain.xml
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below condition should work for both www and without it.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com [NC]
```